How can I properly use scale::Decode to get consistent results?
I'm trying to process a result from a contract call using what's here. It works totally fine when I'm trying to get a u32 result from an ink_e2e test. E.g.
// -- Snip --
let number_of_items = client
    .call(&ink_e2e::alice(), &number_of_items_builder)
    .dry_run()
    .await
    .unwrap();
log!("item count is {}", number_of_items.return_value()); // displays correct item count of 1

The data produced from the call is [0, 1, 0, 0, 0] as seen here:
 CallDryRunResult { exec_result: ContractResult { gas_consumed: Weight { ref_time: 1516764649, proof_size: 41800 }, gas_required: Weight { ref_time: 1516764649, proof_size: 58086 }, storage_deposit: StorageDeposit::Charge(0), debug_message: [], result: Ok(ExecReturnValue { flags: (empty), data: [0, 1, 0, 0, 0] }), events: Some([(), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), ()]) }, _marker: PhantomData<u32> }

and that data is decoded to 1u32. The issue now is, using [0, 1, 0, 0, 0] directly in the scale::Decode method prints 256 and not 1:
let data: Vec<u8> = vec![0, 1, 0, 0, 0];
let num: u32 = scale::Decode::decode(&mut data.as_ref()).unwrap();
log::info!("num {}", num); // displays 256

The question now, why am I getting inconsistent results? What is the return_value method doing differently? And how can I get the above example to produce the expected results?

are you sure your return type is u32 and not Result<u32>? Result is prepended with 0, so 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 -> Ok(u32) would explain that

@dastansam the return type from the contract is u32. Removing the first 0 in the data produces the correct result, as you stated. So I think whether or not the actual contract call returns a Result, the data is always converted to an encoded Result. Thanks

great! I wrote an answer with detailed links if someone stumbles upon similar issue in the future.

return_value() returns the value wrapped in Result and this is why it is prepended with 0 - Ok(1)
